# How to restart array once filled on windows form?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, methods, random

I created a form which asked the user to guess the number. I created an array on 100 ints, created a method to get random numbers to fill the array. All is working fine but I am required to create another method which resets the array back to 0 once 100 guesses are made, and it just seems to let me keep going and going in my current set up. How do I make sure my array is filling up and not just restarting with every button click, then how do I reset it? Again this runs great just not meeting all my requirements.

Here is the code from my array and method and where I am calling it at:

```
int[] rndArray = new int[100];
    int wrong = 1;
    int right = 1;


    public void getNumbers()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int x = 0; x < rndArray.Length; x++)
        {
            rndArray[x] = random.Next(1, 100); 
        }

    }

    public Form1()
    {
        getNumbers();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Then I have two buttons seeing if the guess was correct and letting them guess again.

```
   private void Guess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool num = true;
        for (int x = 0; x < rndArray.Length; x++)
        {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) == rndArray[x])
                { 
                    result.Text = "You Win!";
                    num = true;
                }
                else
                { 
                    result.Text = "Sorry - you loose; the number is: " + rndArray[x];
                    num = false;
                }
        }
        if (num == true)
            correct.Text = "Correct: " + right++;
        else
            incorrect.Text = "Incorrect: " + wrong++;

        mouseHere.Enabled = false;
        Guess.Enabled = false;
        nextGuess.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void nextGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mouseHere.Enabled = true;
        Guess.Enabled = true;
        nextGuess.Enabled = false;
        hint.Text = "??";
        textBox1.Text = "";
        result.Text = "";
        getNumbers();

    }
```

I called the method again so it would not just generate the same number for each guess.

Comment: So you just need to keep a counter for the number of guesses made and fill the array again when it's at 100?

Comment: You probably only need to call `getNumbers()` only if they guess correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a `GuessingGame` class and raise an event when the 100th guess is made? You can reset the array and guess counter.

Something like:

```
public class GuessingGame {
   private int[] RandomNumbers; 
   private GuessCount = 0;

   // constructor
   public GuessingGame () {
       this.guessCount = 0;
       this.randomNumbers = this.RandomNumberGenerator();
   }

   public void AddGuess(int guess) {
      // increment guessCount
      // check for a winner and/or 100th guess
      // raise a correct guess event if correct
      // raise 100th guess event if 100th guess occurs
   }

   private int[] RandomNumberGenerator() {
      // return your array of random numbers
   }

   ...more stuff...
}
```

You'll want to declare a couple of simple eventhandler classes to do whatever you need them to do and then fire them from your GuessingGame class. That's a bit much to code for you, so I'll let you do that on your own. This should get you started in the right OO direction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx. This is a tutorial on events that is pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is a counter :

```
    int count = 0;
    private void Guess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (count < 100)
        {
            count++;
            // checks user input ...
        }
        else
        {
            count = 0;
            // reset the array by getting fresh numbers
            getNumbers();
        }
    }
```

you can also reset the array in a loop and setting It's members's values to `0` .